# OpenCV blur creating linesblob like areas

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, openframeworks

I'm using `OpenCV` with a very high kernel (50 and higher) to get a very exaggerated blur effect. 
I am getting these weird line/area like effects on the generated imagery. Please refer to the wall area on the image below.

Is this something that is inherent to blurring at a very high kernel size? 
What would be some techniques to smooth out and eliminate this effect?

I am using `OpenFrameworks` with the `ofxCV` addon. The relevant part of my code is just

```
 blur(camScaled, 51);
```

If you are not familiar `ofxCV` is essentially a bridge and maps back to this `OpenCV` call in the end.

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void blur( InputArray src, OutputArray dst,
                    Size ksize, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1),
                    int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

[image: blured image]

Comment: What does the input image look like? I suppose this is an artefact of blurring each of the RGB layers separately. Maybe try doing this in HSV or some similar colour space?

Comment: It's the frame read directly from the iPhone camera. From what I'm seeing in this library there is no real separation of the channels on this level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is pretty normal because blurring means averaging the pixels value through the Kernel.

You should try an edge-preserving filter such as bilateral filter.
If you still want to use a "classic" blur you could try the median blur instead of mean blur, that should give you at least a more attenuated result.

Comment: Yes, I have come to the same conclusion and using a median filter now. Since I am only interested in the blurry effect I am wondering if adding a slight grainy noise before doing the filter would make it have less of this visual effect.

Comment: Median filter is done to specifically remove these kind of noise, so it will remove them with the same result. A mean will spread the noise so it would go worst. (P.s. mark as accepted?)